# sunspot index using dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I am trying to integrate sunspot Solr in my Ruby application
I am using dynamic_string for indexing additional data with my model.
However I am getting error

```
searchable do
    text :name
    integer :id
    text :thumbnail_ref
    integer :health_condition_id
    dynamic_string :standard_codes, stored: true do
      st_codes().inject({}) do |hash, e|
        logger.info e.standard
         logger.info e.standard_code
         hash.merge(e.standard.to_sym => e.standard_code)
        logger.info hash
      end
    end

  end

  def st_codes()
    Standard.find_standards_by_health_condition(198)
  end
```

NoMethodError (undefined method `merge' for true:TrueClass):
  app/models/content.rb:35:in`block (3 levels) in '
  app/models/content.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in '

I am not clear about this error.Any help here is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you inject you have to return the injected hash for the following iterations.
atm you get a boolean True from logger.info.

change to this

```
  st_codes().inject({}) do |hash, e|
     logger.info e.standard
     logger.info e.standard_code
     hash.merge!(e.standard.to_sym => e.standard_code)
     logger.info hash
     hash
  end
```